# Angular on iziModal, ng-click inside iziModal not working

Tags: angular

I am new to angular js, I dont have an idea why ng-click button inside an izimodal not firing. But when the button outside the pop up modal its working. Is there anyway to make this work? Really appreciate your help.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
app.controller('memberdata',function($scope, $http, $window){
$scope.addnew = function () {
alert('click');
}
});
```

html code

```
<div class="content-panel" ng-controller="memberdata">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-transparent" ng-click="addmodal()"><i class="icon-plus3"></i> ADD MEMBER</button>


<!--MODAL TO SHOW-->
<div ng-show="AddModal" id="izimodalapp_admin" data-iziModal-title="ADD ADMINISTRATOR" class="modal">
<div class="modal_title"><h3>MEMBER</h3></div>
<!--Not firing button when click-->
 <div class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="addnew()"><i class="icon-paperplane"></i> SAVE</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the scope of your controller "memberdata" is different from the modal one.

"angularUtils.directives.dirPagination" must have it's own controller so when you do :

```
$scope.addnew = function () {
    alert('click');
}
```

you are telling the "memberdata" scope to register this function, wich might not be know by the modal controller.

Register it in the modal controller if you want your modal to be able to access it.

And just fyi, it is good practice in AngularJS to register controllers members inside controller and not just it's scope.

do :

```
var ctrl = this; // Create closure of controller instance
ctrl.addnew = function() { alert('click') }
```

and then call it from template like this :

```
Myctrl.addnew()
```

Comment: Yes. Im wondering why it is working on bootstrap modal. But when i integrate to izimodal not working.